# JDBC Sink Connector ConnectException - Table "schema"."table" is missing and auto-creation is disabled for oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to sink data from kafka topic "kafka2.INVENTORY.PRODUCT" to table "product_target" under schema name "tinventory" with Oracle DB. This sink I am trying with the DB connection user "jdbcsinkuser".

Doing this I am getting error as

```
ERROR [sink-to-target|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-to-target-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Table "tinventory"."PRODUCT_TARGET" is missing and auto-creation is disabled (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:609)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table "tinventory"."PRODUCT_TARGET" is missing and auto-creation is disabled
```

```
{
    "name": "sink-to-target",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "kafka2.INVENTORY.PRODUCT",
        "table.name.format": "PRODUCT_TARGET",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclpdb1",
        "connection.user": "jdbcsinkuser",
        "connection.password": "jdbc",
        "transforms": "unwrap,InsertField",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "pk.fields": "PRODUCTID",
        "insert.mode":"upsert",
        "delete.enabled":true,
        "delete.retention.ms":100,
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.field": "SOURCE",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.value": "LEGACY-SYS"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you need to consider adding the below config field to enable auto creating the tables and it should work fine.

`"auto.create":"true"`

However, it worth mentioning that it might not work with Oracle and MySql dialects in a special cases where you set `pk.mode:true` along with the `auto.create:true`

Quoted from the [JDBC sink docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#ddl-support).

> Database performance could be adversely affected if Kafka Connect auto-creates a table and uses data types that are inefficient for the target database.

> Confluent recommends you review the data types used in conjunction with your database administrator, or pre-create the table before loading it.
> With some JDBC dialects–for example, the Oracle and MySQL dialects–an exception can occur if you set pk.mode to kafka and auto.create to true. The exception occurs because the connector maps STRING to a variable length string (for example, TEXT) and not a fixed length string (for example, VARCHAR(256)). A primary key must have a fixed length. To avoid this exception, consider the following:
> Do not set auto.create to true.
> Create the database table and primary key data type in advance.

Comment: I am trying to setup replication process on existing table, so table creation is not an option for me. And DBA want to restrict jdbc sink user to only insert/update/read mode to this table only. So I can't use actual schema under which table is.

Comment: I think then you have to create the tables manually before hand, if the connector won't be able to do it, and this is option requires high maintainability from your DBA side.

Comment: Yes and there connector is failing to detect table under different schema. Thats problem I am facing.